# Polynomial problems in graph classes defined by forbidden induced cyclic subgraphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

Let $C$ be a graph class defined by a finite
number of forbidden induced subgraphs, all
of which are cyclic (contain at least one cycle).

> Are there graph problems that can be solved in
>   polynomial time for $C$ other than Clique and Clique
>   cover?

If I remember correctly, this is impossible for
independent set (unless $P=NP$).

Search in graphclasses.org didn't find any.

A class for which Clique and Clique cover are
polynomial is [(C5,C6,X164,X165,sunlet4,triangle)-free](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1022.html)

Comment: Crossposted on cstheory, negative answer there:  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/24876/polynomial-problems-in-graph-classes-defined-by-forbidden-induced-cyclic-subgrap#24882